# Evenly spreading study over 20 days?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics, probability-distributions

Want to study $8$ hours a day, and $4$ hours on exam days.

Want to study all exams exactly the same amount of time total.

Exams in $10$,$13$,$19$,$20$ days from start.

What is the daily distribution of study per class? Given that it remains the same for the first $9$ days, changes again at $13$ days, $19$ and $20$.

I imagine this $is$ possible to determine

---

Example:

---

Day 1 - Day 9

Class 1: 4 hours

Class 2: 2 hours

Class 3: 1 hour

Class 4: 1 hour

---

Day 11 - Day 13

Class 2: 4 hours

Class 3: 2 hours

Class 4: 2 hours

---

Day 15 - Day 18

Class 3: 4 hours

Class 4: 4  hours

Comment: Are you considering that you are able to work for 8 hours on exam days?

Comment: @user88595 Actually no, make it 4 hours of study on an exam day(since I travel as well).

Comment: I actually recommend taking the evening off before your exam; or some light studying. Also, I find that breaks make one's studying time more effective. Reagan said: "It is not the years in your life, but the life your years. I say that it is not the hours in your studying, but the studying in your hours.

Comment: @ChrisK Probably true, regardless I am still really confused as to why I can't work this out.

Comment: @user142198, is this a problem OR you are asking practical advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub1=subject 1, Sub2=subject 2, Sub3=subject 3, Sub4=subject 4.

Asuumed that on 10th day you have sub1 exam, on 13th day you have sub2 exam, on 19th and 20th days sub3 and sub4 exams respectively.

[image]

Comment: Only subject $3,4$ are time equivalent?

Comment: @DisplayName, each subject gets 36 hours.

Comment: Now I feel silly, I did the common mistake of thinking 14 to 18 is 4 days, but it is really 5(inclusive).